# Hypothesis of Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Consider a function $f : R^2 \rightarrow R$ given by $f(x,y)= x^2 - y^3.$ I need to check whether the hypothesis of Implicit function theorem hold for $f$ at the point $(0,0)$.

For this, I first calculated the matrix $M(x,y)$ formed by differentiating this function with respect to $y$. $M(x,y) = -3y^2$. It's clearly non-invertible at $(0,0)$. I am stuck here as non-invertibility gives me an inconclusive test. How do I show that hypothesis of Implicit function theorem holds here or not?

Comment: For the condition of IFT, don't you need to check if $\nabla f$ is surjective at $(0,0)$?

Comment: ok.. So, $\nabla f = (2x , -3y^2)$ which is $(0,0)$ at $(0,0)$. Is it enough to prove our hypothesis? I think  $\nabla f$ isn't surjective. So the hypothesis fails?

Comment: That means $\nabla f$ is not surjective and so the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: So at no points our hypothesis holds true?

Comment: Well $\nabla f = (0,0)$ only when $(x, y) = (0,0)$ so the condition of IFT holds whenever $(x, y) \neq (0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct. So, you have verified that the hypotheses of the Implicit Function Theorem are *not* satisfied by $f$ at the point $(0,0)$.

Additionally, note that at any point $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, either $D_1 f(x,y) \neq 0$ or $D_2 f(x,y) \neq 0$. So, the hypotheses of the Implicit Function Theorem will be satisfied by $f$ at any point $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = 0$ except $(0,0)$.